# Python round to 1 decimal place if the decimal is not 0

Tags: python

So the following rounding would occur:

```
1.0  => 1
1.1  => 1.1
1.01 => 1
1.09 => 1.1
```

I would probably just look into the string if left to my own devices, but that feels dirty, is there a more elegant way?

Comment: For your case `format(f, '.1f').rstrip('0').rstrip('.')`